# python curses addstr y-offset: strange behavior with unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, curses, python-curses

I am having trouble with python3 curses and unicode:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import curses
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

def doStuff(stdscr):
  offset = 3
  stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "わたし")
  stdscr.addstr(0, offset, 'hello', curses.A_BOLD)
  stdscr.getch() # pauses until a key's hit

curses.wrapper(doStuff)
```

I can display unicode characters just fine, but the y-offset argument to addstr ("offset" in my code) is not acting as expected; my screen displays "わたhello" instead of "わたしhello"

In fact the offset has very strange behavior:

```
- 0:hello
- 1:わhello
- 2:わhello
- 3:わたhello
- 4:わたhello
- 5:わたしhello
- 6:わたしhello
- 7:わたし hello
- 8:わたし  hello
- 9:わたし   hello
```

Note that the offset is not in bytes, since the characters are 3-byte unicode characters:

```
>>>len("わ".encode('utf-8'))
3
>>> len("わ")
1
```

I'm running python 4.8.3 and curses.version is "b'2.2'".

Does anyone know what's going on or how to debug this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing 3 double-width characters.  That is, each of those takes up two cells.

The length of the string in *characters* (or *bytes*) is not necessarily the same as the number of cells used for each character.

Python curses is just a thin layer over ncurses.

I'd expect the characters in lines 1,3,5 to be erased by putting a character onto the second cell of those double-width characters (ncurses is supposed to do this...), but that detail could be a bug in the terminal emulator).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response from Thomas, I found the wcwidth package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wcwidth) which has a function to return the length of a unicode string in cells.

Here's a full working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import curses
import locale
from wcwidth import wcswidth

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

def doStuff(stdscr):
  foo = "わたし"
  offset = wcswidth(foo)
  stdscr.addstr(0, 0, foo)
  stdscr.addstr(0, offset, 'hello', curses.A_BOLD)
  stdscr.getch() # pauses until a key's hit

curses.wrapper(doStuff)
```